# Adding border radius property changes color of the border

Tags: css, html

I have looked at similar questions asked before and did not find this to be the same.
I wanted to create row border on hover and added css with left and right borders for the first and last cells in the row respectively.

My HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr><td>1111111</td><td>22222222</td><td>3333333333</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4444444</td><td>55555555</td><td>6666666666</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7777777</td><td>88888888</td><td>9999999999</td></tr>
</table>
```

My css:

```
table {
  border-collapse: seperate; 
  border-spacing:0;
}
tr:hover td {
  border-top: 1px groove #E8E8E8;
  border-bottom: 1px groove #E8E8E8;
}
tr:hover td:first-child {
  border-left: 1px groove #E8E8E8;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
tr:hover td:last-child {
  border-right: 1px groove #E8E8E8;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

But adding the border radius makes the border for the cells on the ends lighter.
I have created a JSFiddle for it at [Border radius changes color](https://jsfiddle.net/qtmqf0gw/8/)

I have been using Chrome 55 which changed the color for the first and last cells, but only on top.  Using Safari 10 changes the color for both bottom and top borders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure, but it seems to be some wonky anti-aliasing, worsened by the use of a groove at 1px. Using either a groove at 2px or a solid 1px seems to fix it, although it still lops off a bit on the sides. Is that intentional or also unwanted?

Comment: I ended up using solid. Using 1px groove and border radius is not working.

Answer (score 0):

try this css code

```
    table {
border-collapse: seperate; 
border-spacing:0;
}
tr:hover td {
  border-top: 1px groove #E8E8E8;
  border-bottom: 2px groove #E8E8E8;
}
tr:hover td:first-child {
  border-left: 1px groove #E8E8E8;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
tr:hover td:last-child {
  border-right: 2px groove #E8E8E8;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

change the right and bottom borders width to 2 pixels

Comment: Changing border width looks like it fixes the problem on browser but not all of them.